# How do I implement double buffering in the winapi?

Tags: winapi, double-buffering

I can't stop the flickering. I got the advice to add dubbel-buffering. How do I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace {
    const int ID_NEW = 1;
    const int ID_QUIT = 2;
    const int ID_ABOUT = 3;
    const int NORTH_BUTTON_ID = 4;
    const int SOUTH_BUTTON_ID = 5;
    const int WEST_BUTTON_ID = 6;
    const int EAST_BUTTON_ID = 7;
    const int ID_FINISHED_GAME = 8;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xStart = 0;
    int yStart = 0;
    int windowHeight = 400;
    int windowWidth = 500;
    char level1[20][21];
    int noOfMoves = 0;
}

void readLevel(string fileName, char level[20][21]) {
    char character{};
    ifstream file(fileName);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file >> character) {
            level[j][i] = character;
            if (level[j][i] == 's') {
                y = yStart = j;
                x = xStart = i;
            }
            if (++i % 20 == 0) {
                i = 0;
                j++;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}

void restart(){
    x = xStart;
    y = yStart;
    noOfMoves = 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HDC hdc{ 0 };
    PAINTSTRUCT ps{ 0 };
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)){
        case ID_ABOUT:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"About this program!", L"About", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        case ID_NEW:
            restart();
            return 0;
        case ID_QUIT:
            if (MessageBox(0, L"Do you really want to quit?", L"Are you sure?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES) {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
        case NORTH_BUTTON_ID:
            if (level1[y - 1][x] != '1') {
                y -= 1;
                noOfMoves++;
            }
            break;
        case SOUTH_BUTTON_ID:
            if (level1[y + 1][x] != '1'){
                y += 1;
                noOfMoves++;
            }
            break;
        case WEST_BUTTON_ID:
            if (level1[y][x - 1] != '1'){
                x -= 1;
                noOfMoves++;
            }
            break;
        case EAST_BUTTON_ID:
            if (level1[y][x + 1] != '1') {
                x += 1;
                noOfMoves++;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (level1[y][x] == 'e') {
            wstring moves = L"Congratulations, you finished the game with " + to_wstring(noOfMoves);
            MessageBox(hwnd, moves.c_str(), L"Finished game", MB_OK);
        }
    case WM_PAINT: {
                       char wall[2] = { "W" };
                       char floor[2] = { 'W' };
                       char current[2] = { "X" };
                       char goal[2] = { "G" };
                       wstring position = L"Position = [" + to_wstring(x) + L", " + to_wstring(y) + L"]";
                       wstring moves = L"Move = " + to_wstring(noOfMoves);
                       hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                       TextOut(hdc, 20, 200, position.c_str(), position.size());
                       TextOut(hdc, 20, 220, moves.c_str(), moves.size());
                       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                           for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                               if (level1[j][i] == '1') {
                                   SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                                   SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                                   TextOut(hdc, 14 * i + 190, 14 * j + 20, LPCTSTR(wall), strlen(wall));
                               }
                               SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                               if (level1[j][i] == '0') {
                                   SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                                   TextOut(hdc, 14 * i + 190, 14 * j + 20, LPCTSTR(floor), strlen(floor));
                               }
                               SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                               if (i == x && j == y)
                                   TextOut(hdc, 14 * i + 190, 14 * j + 20, LPCTSTR(current), strlen(current));
                               if (level1[j][i] == 'e')
                                   TextOut(hdc, 14 * i + 190, 14 * j + 20, LPCTSTR(goal), strlen(goal));
                           }
                       }
                       EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                       break;

    }
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return true;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

HMENU CreateMainMenu() {
    HMENU main = CreateMenu();
    HMENU file = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, ID_NEW, L"&New");
    AppendMenu(file, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, 0);
    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, ID_QUIT, L"&Quit");
    AppendMenu(main, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)file, L"&File");
    HMENU help = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenu(help, MF_STRING, ID_ABOUT, L"&About");
    AppendMenu(main, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)help, L"&Help");
    return main;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    readLevel("level1.txt", level1);
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyWindowClass";
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(L"MyWindowClass", L"The Maze",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, CreateMainMenu(), hInstance, 0);
    HWND buttonNorth = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"NORTH", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 20, 150, 40, hwnd, (HMENU)NORTH_BUTTON_ID, hInstance, 0);
    HWND buttonSouth = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"SOUTH", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 60, 150, 40, hwnd, (HMENU)SOUTH_BUTTON_ID, hInstance, 0);
    HWND buttonEast = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"EAST", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 140, 150, 40, hwnd, (HMENU)EAST_BUTTON_ID, hInstance, 0);
    HWND buttonWest = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"WEST", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 100, 150, 40, hwnd, (HMENU)WEST_BUTTON_ID, hInstance, 0);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    BOOL isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                isRunning = false;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a bitmap the same size as your client rect, draw everything on that bitmap, then blit that bitmap to to your window.  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153387/double-buffering-win32-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinAPI Double-buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895305/winapi-double-buffering)

Comment: Your casts are wrong. Why are you casting string types? You are lying to the compiler and it will take its revenge.  Why are you using C style strings at all?

Comment: Met with non-answers and short-sighted criticism, not even knowing if there is a reason, there might be, but the question wasn't about what they could do better, was it? Double buffering is pretty simple, just make another HBITMAP, attach an HDC to it, use BitBlt to copy the contents of off-screen drawing.  You can use CreateCompatibleBitmap to guarantee it is the same format as the window. You could either allocate a screen sized bitmap, so you don't have to keep resizing, or you can be dynamic and resize it every time one of the WM_SIZ.* comes into play. Use the COPY mode to copy the pixels.

Answer (score 6):

As member *Retired Ninja* said, you make compatible device context with the original one ( `hdc` in your case ), and create a bitmap compatible with your original device context ( bitmap size is equal to the size of your rectangle where you paint your stuff ).

Then select this newly created bitmap into compatible device context you just created and draw everything on it.

Then you just `BitBlt(...)` the compatible device context into original one.

Do not forget to perform proper cleanup in order to avoid GDI leaks.

Your code should look like this:

```
case WM_PAINT: 
    {
        // skipped the initialization part to preserve space
        // just copy those, they are irrelevant for your problem

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // create memory DC and memory bitmap where we shall do our drawing

        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );

        // get window's client rectangle. We need this for bitmap creation.
        RECT rcClientRectangle;
        GetClientRect( hwnd, &rcClientRect );

        // now we can create bitmap where we shall do our drawing
        HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, 
            rcClientRect.right - rcClientRect.left, 
            rcClientRect.bottom - rcClientRect.top );

        // we need to save original bitmap, and select it back when we are done,
        // in order to avoid GDI leaks!
        HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( memDC, bmp );

        // now you draw your stuff in memory dc; 
        // just substitute hdc with memDC in your drawing code, 
        // like I did below:

        TextOut( memDC, //...
        TextOut( memDC, //...
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
            {
                if (level1[j][i] == '1') 
                {
                    SetTextColor( memDC, //...
                    SetBkColor( memDC, //...
                    TextOut( memDC, //...
                }
                SetBkColor( memDC, //...
                if (level1[j][i] == '0') 
                {
                    SetTextColor( memDC, //...
                    TextOut( memDC, //...
                }
                SetTextColor( memDC, //...
                if (i == x && j == y)
                    TextOut( memDC, //...
                if (level1[j][i] == 'e')
                    TextOut( memDC, //...
            }
        }

        // OK, everything is drawn into memory DC, 
        // now is the time to draw that final result into our target DC

        BitBlt( hdc, 0, 0, rcClientRect.right - rcClientRect.left, 
            rcClientRect.bottom - rcClientRect.top, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

        // all done, now we need to cleanup
        SelectObject( memDC, oldBmp ); // select back original bitmap
        DeleteObject( bmp ); // delete bitmap since it is no longer required
        DeleteDC( memDC );   // delete memory DC since it is no longer required

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
```